# OpenWeatherMap Forecast Invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, weather-api, openweathermap

When I call openweathermap with:

```
http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Milan,it&lang=it&units=metric&APPID=*****************', res => {
        res.on('data', function (openweather) { ...
```

I get a partial string:

```
{"cod":"200","message":0.2451,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1509462000,"main":{"temp":15.86,"temp_min":14.41,"temp_max":15.86,"pressure":1010.76,"sea_level":1037.47,"grnd_level":1010.76,"humidity":70,"temp_kf":1.45},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"cielo sereno","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0.24,"deg":257.001},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-31 15:00:00"},{"dt":1509472800,"main":{"temp":9.8,"temp_min":8.72,"temp_max":9.8,"pressure":1011.36,"sea_level":1038.47,"grnd_level":1011.36,"humidity":86,"temp_kf":1.08},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"cielo sereno","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0.46,"deg":256.507},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-31 18:00:00"},{"dt":1509483600,"main":{"temp":6.87,"temp_min":6.15,"temp_max":6.87,"pressure":1011.98,"sea_level":1039.25,"grnd_level":1011.98,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0.72},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"cielo sereno","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{
undefined:1
{"cod":"200","message":0.2451,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1509462000,"main":{"temp":15.86,"temp_min":14.41,"temp_max":15.86,"pressure":1010.76,"sea_level":1037.47,"grnd_level":1010.76,"humidity":70,"temp_kf":1.45},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"cielo sereno","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0.24,"deg":257.001},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-31 15:00:00"},{"dt":1509472800,"main":{"temp":9.8,"temp_min":8.72,"temp_max":9.8,"pressure":1011.36,"sea_level":1038.47,"grnd_level":1011.36,"humidity":86,"temp_kf":1.08},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"cielo sereno","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":0.46,"deg":256.507},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-10-31 18:00:00"},{"dt":1509483600,"main":{"temp":6.87,"temp_min":6.15,"temp_max":6.87,"pressure":1011.98,"sea_level":1039.25,"grnd_level":1011.98,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0.72},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"cielo sereno","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{
```

While calling the same URL with postman or from browser I get a valid JSON.
Also using some npm module I obtain the same result.

Comment: You have to provide more information. What is the `http` object? Is it the native Node module or?

Comment: Have a look at the example here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback
and make sure to specificly notice this line `res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });`

Comment: @Milkncookiez yes that's the native module http.

Comment: @Molda thanks the solution is to do:
 let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {

Probably because the text is too long. I'm a beginner with node and until now I worked with shorter messages,